# DC motor vs Stepper motor vs Continuous servo - Which one should I use?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, stepper-motor, servo

I'm about to build a robot arm (trust me, I've already got most of it down), but I don't know which type of motor to use. From what I understand, DC motors do the same thing as Stepper motors but without feedback. I, in this situation, don't really need feedback, because the robot arm is remote control (That should be the new thing: R/C Robot arms!). Anyways, a continues servo does the same thing too with a messed up feedback, so basically they do the same thing and I don't know which one to choose!

Also, just out of curiosity, would it be better to use a DC motor or a Stepper motor in a average R/C car?

Comment: I was with you until the "messed up feedback" part.

Comment: Voting to close as a basic "shopping" or "help me choose" type question.

Comment: "(trust me, I've already got most of it down)" -> you haven't even choosen your actuators, how can we trust you on that ? Refer to st2000 for the anwser "we can't told you what you should choose as we don't know what your arm should be able to do"

Answer (score 4):

A DC motor (suitably geared) can be much more powerful and faster than a stepper motor, but needs a feedback mechanism to obtain precise positioning.

You intend to operate your 'robot' arm by remote control, but "don't need feedback". Without feedback you cannot tell the arm to move to a precise position. However if you are controlling it with an R/C transmitter, and the motor is geared down to a low speed so you can stop the arm when it reaches the position you want, then *you* will be providing the feedback. In that case it isn't really a robot, but just a remote controlled mechanism.

An R/C servo can be made to rotate continuously by disconnecting the feedback pot from the output shaft, then it will rotate continuously when commanded off center. This effectively 'downgrades' the servo to a simple geared motor with H-bridge speed control. This could be used for traction motors in an R/C vehicle, but is not good for steering.

The average R/C car uses a servo (geared DC motor with feedback) for steering because the operator needs it to turn in proportion to moving the stick or wheel on the transmitter. Without that automatic tracking, the operator would have to rely on visual feedback and quick reflexes - and driving fast would be impossible.

Cheap toy R/C cars often use a simpler steering mechanism which just has a motor that rotates until it hits a stop at full lock, and a spring to center it when the motor is turned off. These are harder to steer because you only have 3 positions (left/center/right) but even that is better than allowing it to rotate 360° with no defined positions.

Answer (score 1):

None of these motors necessarily feedback their position or speed to an external controller.

A DC brush motor rotates when voltage is applied.  The direction depends on polarity.

Common servos contain a DC brush motor, an integrated controller, a gear box and position feed back to the integrated controller.  External power and control signals, usually in the form of a synchronization pulse and position pulse, are supplied by an external controller.

When DC voltage is supplied to one set of stepping motor coils the stepping motor moves to that position and stops.  Consider an imaginary stepping motor with 3 sets of coils.  Voltage is applied to 1 set of coils at a time.  The direction of rotation of a stepping motor depends on the order voltage is applied to each set of coils. The speed depends on how fast voltage is switched from coil set to coil set. Real stepping motors combine more complex voltage patterns with fewer coils.  [Unipolar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepper_motor#Unipolar_motors) and [Bipolar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepper_motor#Bipolar_motors) are examples of real stepping motors.

Note, there are other types of motors, servos and steppers.  Selection should be based on the application.  Such as delicate finger work verses high torque arm movement.

Comment: A 'basic stepping motor' does **'not have 3 sets of coils'**. A 'basic' bipolar stepper motor has two coils, and a 'basic' unipolar stepper motor has two coils, but they look like 4 coils when you drive them. A Brushless DC motor (BLDC) has 3 sets of coils.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @gbulmer.  I'll alter my answer.

Comment: No, that isn't what I meant. I think you are still describing a Brushless DC motor (BLDC). Also your term 'coil sets' suggests you are describing a BLDC motor.  Further "the direction of rotation of a stepping motor depends on the order voltage is applied to each set of coils" is not sufficient explanation. The direction of rotation of a bipolar stepper motor depends on the order *and polarity* of voltages applied to each coil, unlike a 'basic' BLDC motor.